# Javascript - waiting for a click before ending function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, json

I have made what is essentially a lightbox whereby if a change requires the user to confirm their password, this lightbox pops up and the user enters there password etc.

I am triggering the function like this:

```
if(verifyPassword())
{
    //apply change
}
```

The verify function is:

```
function verifyPassword() {
$('#confirmpasswordoverlay').fadeIn(300);

$('#submit').click(function() {
    $.post('', { password: $('input[name=password]').val() }, 
            function(check) {
                if(check.error)
                {
                    if(check.password)
                    {
                        //show password error
                        return false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //show error
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }, 'json');
});

}
```

Basically I am needing the function to wait until `#submit` is clicked to return either true or false.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since jQuery `1.5.0`, you can do apply some magic with `Deferred objects`:

```
$.when( verifyPassword() ).done(function() {
    // do something
});
```

You would need to re-write `verifyPassword()` a little:

```
function verifyPassword() {
    var Notify = $.Deferred();
    $('#confirmpasswordoverlay').fadeIn(300);

    $('#submit').click(function() {
        $.post('', { password: $('input[name=password]').val() }, 
                function(check) {
                    if(check.error) {
                        if(check.password) {
                            //show password error
                            Notify.resolve();
                        }
                        else {
                            //show error
                            Notify.reject();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }, 'json');
        });

    return Notify.promise();
}
```

This might not be the most elegant way of achieving your goal here, I'm just saying you *could* do it in a way like this :-)

Comment: I got to test this when get home, never knew about this technique. Looks interesting.

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I was looking for! One thing though, if the user gets the password wrong and clicks again it will not run the original function: `$.when( verifyPassword() ).done(function() { ...`

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out... Simply don't put Notify.reject() where an incorrect password error has occured. Thanks again, i wasn't even aware v1.5 was released!

Comment: @jAndy rather then having your own `$.Deferred` object you can return the deferred object from `$.post`

Comment: @Ratlos: you could, but not in this particular requirement of the OP, since the jXHR object would only be available after a click

Answer (score 2):

Don't stall, instead provide a callback:

```
function verifyPassword(f) {
    /**
    * Do all your logic here, then callback to the passed function
    */
    f(result);
}
verifyPassword(function (correct) {
    if (correct) {
        /* Continue */
    }
    else { /* Other */ }
});
```

Comment: It wont work, as `$.post` wont return anything to parent function. He does needs a new function that he can call from within `$.post` callback function

Comment: @Pablo: I'm omitting the `$.post` code, `f(result)` would go in the callback from that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to convert your `$.post()` call into the more generic `$.ajax()` jQuery call, and pass in `async: false`. Something like:

```
$.ajax('', { async:false, data: {password:...}, success: function() {
    // ... success callback ...
}});
```

Comment: Never use `async=false` It locks the UI. There are very view cases for it use. and this is _not_ one of them